# PhantomJS Install Centos 5.5

Tags: linux, phantomjs

I'm encountering an error while running the phantoms hello.js statement.

> phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've checked the modules that are installed (ldd phantomjs):

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7732000)
libfreetype.so.6 => not found
libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb7722000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb7719000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76fd000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7612000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb75e8000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75ca000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7433000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7733000)
```

As you can see, two lib's are missing. So I've checked [this blog](http://www.sameerhalai.com/blog/how-to-install-phantomjs-on-a-centos-server/) explaining the errors.

> yum install freetype => results in => Package
>   freetype-2.3.11-15.el6_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>
> yum install fontconfig => results in => Package
>   fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

But still it is not working. What's wrong.... I'm not a linux expert. I'm running CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Comment: your question actually solved my problem.. thanks! after running the commands above phantomjs works for me.

Answer (score 0):

in general,

```
yum provides libfreetype.so.6
```

then install the right one

e.g.

`yum install freetype-2.4` or `yum install freetype` or `yum install freetype-freeworld` etc..

do the same for the other missing library, which will popup once you install freetype.